# How to get local variable between ruby script

Tags: ruby, rspec

Unable to get local variable value of module in one .rb into another .rb file. Am trying to get driverDetailsMap variable value from setup.rb into Scriptrunner.rb file. But i always got the issue as undefined method `driverDetailsMap' for Setup:Module (NoMethodError).

Setup.rb

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "rspec"
require 'spreadsheet'

  module Setup

    if ENV["RAKE_CALL"] == "true"   
        $driverDetailsMap = Hash.new
        inputMap = Hash.new
        workbook = Spreadsheet.open 'src/config/Config.xls'

        deviceConfigSheet = workbook.worksheet 'DeviceConfig'
        totalColumnCount = deviceConfigSheet.column_count
        startingColumn = 1  

        while startingColumn <= totalColumnCount-1

          deviceConfigSheet.each do |row|
            inputMap[row[0]] = row[startingColumn]
          end

          if inputMap.[]('PLATFORM_NAME') == 'Web-Firefox'
            driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
            base_url = inputMap.[]('DRIVER_URL')
            accept_next_alert = true
            driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
            driver.manage.window.maximize
            driver.get(base_url + "/")
          end

             driverDetailsMap[inputMap.[]('DEVICE_IDENTIFIER')] = driver
            startingColumn += 1
        end
      end
end
```

ScriptRunner.rb

```
require "rspec"
require 'spreadsheet'
#require 'setup'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/setup.rb'
#include Setup

 puts Setup::driverDetailsMap
 puts "TESTING <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"

..................
```

Please Help In Advance..

Comment: Why do you need the local variable? What exactly do you want to test?

Comment: Also, your code is not within a test. There is no describe, context, nor it blocks. Make sure you have your test flushed out before declaring that it isn't working. Scope is important. Us understanding what you're actually trying to test is important too- tests are documentation, and you're missing the documentation!

Comment: I want to share driver instance from one ruby script to another script. If it is may be local or global variable.

Answer (score 0):

`$driverDetailsMap` is **the global variable**.

To have an instance variable on `Setup` class, one might do:

```
class Setup
  @driver_details_map = Hash.new
  class << self
    attr_reader :driver_details_map
  end

  ...
end
```

And later access it with

```
Setup.driver_details_map
```

Please note, that I corrected the name of the variable to snake case to conform ruby style guidelines.

Comment: Now am getting empty values like {}

Comment: My scenario is totally different, Am run it from given below Rake file.  command as Rake all
.......... 
    task:testCase1 => ["spec1:setup"] do
  ENV["RAKE_CALL"] = "false"
  Rake::Task["spec:test1"].invoke('Device1', 'testcase1')
end
task:testCase2 => ["spec1:setup"] do
  ENV["RAKE_CALL"] = "false"
  Rake::Task["spec:test2"].invoke('Device2', 'testcase2')
end
multitask :all => ["testCase1", "testCase2"]

Comment: Fo my understanding, First i have initialised the driver_details_map variable . Again require 'Setup.rb' in scriptrunner.rb  resets the driver_details_map variable value. How to get driver_details_map without require 'Setup.rb' in scriptrunner.rb file

Comment: The question you have stated (“Unable to get local variable value of module in one .rb into another .rb file.”) is perfectly answered above. Whether you have any other questions, don’t hesitate to open new questions via “Ask Question” button on the top left of every page on SO.